# Get all data after linking to other page using $_GET

Tags: php, mysqli, get

I'am very glad to haveall of u programmers. I need your help for my code. Below is my code:

-survey.php

```html
<td><center><a href="survey.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '"></b><font size="2">Not Complete</a></center></td></tr>';
```

While this is the page after I clink link where it GET the user_id.

-page.php

```html
$staffid = (int)$_GET['user_id'];
```

In page.php, I only get user_id data only. My question is how do I want to get all data from $_GET['user_id'], such as their email, address, etc.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: then just use that user_id that you got and just make a select statement from db

Comment: u mean like this?:
$query = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM staff WHERE staff_id = '$staffid'");

Comment: you must select based on what the user_id is. thats what you're getting anyway. and since you're using mysqli, use prepared statements instead  of directly concatenating variables inside query statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page you want all the data, page.php, you need to run something like this (In this case a PDO prepared statement, you can do that with mysqli, too):

```
try {
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST . ';dbname=' . DB , USER_DB, PASS_DB); // replace with your credentials!
    $state = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE user_id = :id");
    $state->execute(array('id' => $_GET['user_id']));
    if ($state->rowCount() > 0) {
    list ($username,$email /* catch all the fields you need ,*/ )=$state->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
    }
    else {
       echo "Nothing found"; }
    $state->closeCursor();
    unset($state, $connection);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
}
```

SIDENOTE:

There seems to be an error in your first line you posted here:

```
<td><center><a href="survey.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '"></b><font size="2">Not Complete</a></center></td></tr>';
                                                                  ^where does this come from?
```

Comment: This is a perfect and secure(enough) example for what you require.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of to make this 100% the best is to check `rowCount()` to ensure something is returned. Other than that, this is the exact answer I would've posted :) good work!

Comment: Added it, with at least a little else :)

Comment: (`if($state->rowCount() > 0) { ...`) --> If it's more than 0, meaning there is a row :P

Comment: Allways a little too quick. Now it should be quite nice

Answer (score 0):

passing the id alone cannot get all the fields you want. Instead create a query where you insert the staff id to get the fields you want

$staffid = (int)$_GET['user_id'];

SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= '".$staffid."'

And Run the query.